# Prevent app from overriding the Android notification bar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have the following simple layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I keep the notification permanently displayed in my app? My SDK-Version is 27. I already tried a lot of the solutions available and none seemed to have worked.

```xml
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

My styles.xml:

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: What theme do you have set on the Activity in the manifest?

Comment: I've edited my original question.

Comment: If you haven't edited the default theme, the default behavior is for the notification bar to stay on the screen. What have you changed as compared to a bare new project?

Comment: I just tried a new empty app, in there it works. I cloned it from a sample project from Github, I'll try to find it.

Comment: I found it: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like SceneForm's BaseARFragment makes the host Activity use immersive mode via an OnWindowFocusChangeListener. I *think* you should be able to add your own OnWindowFocusChangeListener and it would be called after the other one, so you could override this behavior.

```
arFragment.arSceneView?.viewTreeObserver.addOnWindowFocusChangeListener { hasFocus -> 
    if (hasFocus) {
        window.decorView
          .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    }
}
```

Read up on the system UI flags to decide which ones you actually want.

Comment: Where should I add this? In onCreate()? I'm also using Java.

Comment: Found it, the app switched to fullscreen in onWindowFocusChanged.

Comment: Yeah, onCreate. Your question is tagged kotlin.